# How do I match/remove numbers at the beginning of comments in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a list of comments imported into R. Here is an example of how some of the comments are imported -

```
9. This is some string number 1
9This is some string number 2
9 This is some string number 3
9-This is some string number 4
67-68 This is some string number 5
```

Note I saved the comments to a variable called `some_str`

My goal is to print out every line without the number(s) at the beginning of the line. Like this -

```
This is some string number 1
This is some string number 2
This is some string number 3
This is some string number 4
This is some string number 5
```

I have used the code below to handle the first line (`9. This is some string number 1`) above -

```
pattern = "([0-9][.][ ])"
str_replace(some_str, pattern, "")
```

which outputs `This is some string number 1`

However I have having difficulty matching/deleting the other lines. For example if I create the pattern `([0-9][A-Z])` to match "9T" on for the second line, how do I delete only the number 9.

Lastly also note that I'm trying to remove numbers that are only at the beginning of the comment. For example if line 3 has the following comment -

```
"9 This is some string number 2. 2 dogs came to town"
```

I only want to remove 9 at the beginning of the comment. I don't want to remove 2 after the fullstop.

Comment: Is the above example the full range of potential number patterns? I.e. in the last line you not only want to remove the number at the beginning, but also the number after some text (i.e. the 68 after "-"). Is this example the only one where you want to delete two numbers divided by a non-digit?

Comment: Another interpretation of your example code would be to delete everything before the first real A-Z letter appears (i.e. everything before "This"). Please clarify.

Comment: @deschen I do see another pattern that shows up like "67,68 This is some string". And YES to your second comment. I want to delete everything before the first word of each comment. I used "This is a string" just for example but that is not necessarily the string in the real text. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a base R solution.
The pattern used is

```
pattern <- "^[-[:digit:][:punct:][:space:]]*"
```

And it works with all posted test cases.

```
sub(pattern, "", x)
#[1] "This is some string number 1" "This is some string number 2"
#[3] "This is some string number 3" "This is some string number 4"
#[5] "This is some string number 5"
```

The same regex works with the last string:

```
sub(pattern, "", y)
#[1] "This is some string number 2. 2 dogs came to town"
```

A solution with package `stringr` could be

```
library(stringr)

str_remove(x, pattern)
str_remove(y, pattern)
```

**Data**

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = "
9. This is some string number 1
9This is some string number 2
9 This is some string number 3
9-This is some string number 4
67-68 This is some string number 5
", sep = "\n")

y <- "9 This is some string number 2. 2 dogs came to town"
```

Answer (score 6):

Another solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

dat <- data.frame(x = c("67,68 This is my test",
                        "67-68 This is my test",
                        "8 This is my test"))

dat %>%
  mutate(x2 = str_replace(x, pattern = "^[^A-Z]*", ""))
```

which gives:

```
                      x              x2
1 67,68 This is my test This is my test
2 67-68 This is my test This is my test
3     8 This is my test This is my test
```

Comment: Just in case there can be some Unicode strings, the pattern may be changed to `"^\\P{L}+"`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("^[-0-9. ]+", "", v1)
#[1] "This is some string number 1" "This is some string number 2" "This is some string number 3" "This is some string number 4"
#[5] "This is some string number 5"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("9. This is some string number 1", "9This is some string number 2", 
"9 This is some string number 3", "9-This is some string number 4", 
"67-68 This is some string number 5")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
stringr::str_extract("9. This is some string number 1 2. 2 dogs came to town", "^([0-9][.][ ])")
```

This should work.
Just change your pattern to:
**^([0-9][.][ ])**